# abort: HTTP Error 500: No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp ', '/usr/tmp', '/'] on hg push

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

Suddenly I am getting this error on my Ubuntu server when i try to push my local repository onto the server. Can anyone please help me fix this.

Comment: Similar error, and again the issue was server-side machine was full. `: $ hg push
pushing to ssh://.../
searching for changes
remote: abort: No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/home/gabe']
abort: unexpected response: empty string`

Answer (score 5):

That's python on the server side saying "Hey!, none of those 4 directories are places I can write temporary files!".  Check to make sure at least one of them exists, can be written to by the user mercurial is running as *on the server side*, and make sure the disk isn't full.